# How do I bind ListItem to CommandParameter

Tags: c#, wpf, viewmodel

I have a `ListBox` :

```
<ListBox Margin="10" Padding="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- Data template -->
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <!--Image-->
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                    <!--Info-->
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="500" />
                    <!--Options-->
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" /
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Height="50" Width="50" />
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Name: " />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="ID: " />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
                <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding Status}" Command="{Binding CompleteCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainPageViewModel}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I need my `CommandParameter` be the `ListItem` of this `ListBox`.

Comment: ListItem? Do you mean the item with the ID and Status properties?

Comment: Yeap! Exactly !

Comment: YES! Thanks everyone I did it and finished the project!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `AncestorType` to `ListBox` and include `DataContext` in the path:

```
<Button ... Command="{Binding DataContext.CompleteCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></Button>
```

Then the `Command` binding should work provided that the `CompleteCommand` property belongs to the same class as the `Items` property

Comment: Yes, I guess this is the class where the Items property is defined? It might be an idea to post the definition of the MainPageViewModel class.

Comment: You mean `DataContext` is the one which is used to `Bind` `Items` ?

Comment: DataContext returns the DataContext of the ListBox, which is the view model.

Comment: Thanks bro I got you.

Comment: No need. I made stupidly stupid mistake there. I have forgotten to put `public` to my `CompleteCommand`  :(!!!